# Как определить какой вид шифрования был использован

Tags: шифрование

Занимаюсь CTF, и мне надо расшифровать вот это:

> `Guvf_vf_prnfre_pvcure`

Какой вид шифрования использовали и как вы его определили? Существует ли какая-нибудь программа для определения вида шифрования?

Comment: С такой минимальной информации вы ничего не можете сделать. Ни зашифрована ли информация, ни какое из ваших предположений более верное.

Comment: Автор, обратите внимание на комментарий @Fat-Zer к ответу. Там однозначно указан вид шифрования (алфавит циклически сдвинут на 13 (a->n; b->o; c->p; ...)).

Comment: Скорее всего, или замены, или перестановок.

Answer (score 4):

Первое, что приходит в голову - шифр подстановки, так как строка получилась очень регулярной. Все нормальные бинарные шифры превращают открытый текст в неструктурируемый набор битов.

Для проверки я спросил у гугла [онлайн декодировщики для шифров подстановки](https://www.google.com/search?q=substitution%20cipher%20solver). Взял первый в выдаче, понял, что он даёт какую-то туфту. Взял второй, посмотрел на его результат

```
0   -1.187  Unit_it_seated_signed
1   -1.317  Knit_it_seated_signed
2   -1.342  What_at_melted_mashed
3   -1.378  Skin_in_leaned_licked
4   -1.394  This_is_censer_cipher
5   -1.411  Case_se_intend_island
6   -1.455  Whit_it_seated_sighed
7   -1.490  Dior_or_secret_soviet
8   -1.507  What_at_morton_machon
9   -1.524  This_is_balsam_bigham
10  -1.529  Eras_as_poison_patron
11  -1.535  This_is_measel_michel
12  -1.594  Univ_iv_served_signed
13  -1.630  Lies_es_robson_region
14  -1.709  Utin_in_leaned_listed
15  -1.710  Phil_il_sealed_sighed
```

и выбрал вариант №4: `This_is_censer_cipher` - наверняка в задачке CTF должно присутствовать слово *cipher*. Да и в целом это наиболее осмысленное предложение.

Выглядит разумно, хотя расшифрованный текст меня смущает. По идее должно быть **caesar** а не censer, но замена r->a, n->e приведёт к результату This_is_caesar_ciphar, что тоже выглядит немного странно.

УПД. Как правильно отметил в комментарии @Fat-Zer, шифр оказался самым простым - сдвиговым. Не подумал, несмотря на то, что знаки `_` очень даже на него намекали: пробел ASCII код 32, подчеркивание ASCII код 45, разница 13. Итого сдвиговый шифр на 13.

Открытый текст `This is ceaser cipher` с ошибкой в слове *цезарь*. Должно быть `caesar`.

Comment: Учитывая, что это скорей всего действительно шифр Цезаря со сдвигом на 13, то получится «c**ea**ser»... очевидно, опечатка... или его составлял просто какой-то безграмотный человек... а может он просто специально хотел запутать...

Comment: Это называется ROT-13, очень популярный в своё время.